# After exiting interpreter and re-entering, Pickled file not loaded; instead variables revert to base in python

Tags: python, pickle

Firstly, my problem is that my code has a save function for a text game that I am making. The problem is, is that when I load the pickled data, it doesn't load properly and instead the stat variables are when you start the game.

This is the code for the *saveGame()* function:

```
def saveGame():
statList = {'armed':armed,'arms':arms,'bombs':bombs,'exposed':exposed,'foodDrink':foodDrink,'gold':gold,'happy':happy,'health':health,'heat':heat,'heatTier':heatTier,'month':month,'name':name,'nameWait':nameWait,'path':path,'poster':poster,'propa':propa,'status':status,'raidPts':raidPts}
print('► Saving game...')
with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(statList, f)    
print('► Game saved. You can access it by typing "load" at the title.')
TitleScreen()
```

And this is the code for the *loadGame()* function:

```
def loadGame():
    print('► Loading saved game...')
    with open('savefile', 'rb') as f:
        statList = pickle.load(f)
    print('► Game loaded.')
```

When I test the *loadGame()* function after closing and re-opening Python (as if in a return from closing the system situation), I find out that the data is at its default.

These are the default variables that I changed:

gold = 350 (<-- ***This is the variable I tested on by changing it to 355.***)

name = None (<-- ***This also changed to S.G.***)

Is there anything that I can do to make the variables be saved so that when I play a saved file from a **re-enter system situation**, the stats variables will stay the same as I last saved them?

Comment: you are not returning `statList`

Comment: When you say 'returning `statList`, where do I type the line?

Comment: in `loadGame` ofc, in given example it returns `None`

Comment: also if there wasn't previous `'savefile'` it will raise `FileNotFoundError` in **Python 3** and `IOError` in **Python 2.7**

Comment: Edit: The variables were changed in-game. This is also Python 3.6.1.

Comment: can you provide example of main function using `saveGame` and `loadGame`?

Comment: Is the data you're saving (and that you want to load again) coming from global variables (e.g. `armed`, `arms`, etc.)? Your `loadGame` function doesn't make any attempt to update any of them, it just reads the `dict` that was pickled. If you want it to replace the values in the global variables with the values from the dictionary, you need to explicitly write code to do that.

Comment: Note: During an unclosed interpreter session, the dict is saved. However, when I close the session and restart the game, it presents me with the default values.